# How to configure a home network when ethernet connections are made in a line?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch

I have a few question on what the optimal setup of network devices would be given **my current situation**:

I moved into a rented apartment that has a wall plate with two RJ45 sockets in every bedroom / living room. When I tried to connect devices in different rooms to a home network I noticed that the ethernet connections were only made point-to-point between two rooms and, overall, form a line, instead of a star. 
(See picture below.)

[image]

The cable socket connected to the ISP is located in room A and provides up to 400/20 MBit/s of downstream/upstream. My goal is to connect rooms B, C and D in a way that offers a 400 Mbit/s internet connection to devices connected to the wired network and at least 50-100 MBit/s to mobile devices connection via WLAN, even if they are in the far corner of room D.

Since the two RJ45 sockets in each room are not connected, I currently have a switch in each room, connecting both sockets. The cable modem is located in room A, the router (and wireless access point) is located in the hallway (room F). The WAN connection between the cable modem (room A) and the router (room F) thus uses the red and blue connections, which are also part of the LAN. The router is a Fritzbox 4040 with a WAN port and 4 LAN ports. It is connected to the network on both the WAN port and one of its LAN ports. The activity lights on the hallway switch indicate that the router is absolutely spamming itself between its own two ports so I assume that putting WAN and LAN on the same network is not a very pretty solution.

If I understand correctly, a packet sent to a remote device on the internet from an end device in room A is transmitted across the blue and red lines to the router (room F) and then back to the cable modem (room A) along the same lines. Obviously, this effectively halves the available bandwidth for devices in room A and B. Since the LAN consists entirely of Gigabit connections, this is still above the 400 MBit/s limit set by the ISP.

Now my **questions**:

1. Is there a better way to connect the rooms that doesn't require such
   a huge amount of switches?
2. I thought about simply connecting the two RJ45 sockets in each room. This would effectively connect all the sockets to a kind of bus network. Would this cause noticeable performance penalties due to collisions? Note: The total length of the line would be less than 100m.

I also thought about moving the router into room A and installing a dedicated WLAN access point in the hallway (room F), which would solve the problem of using the blue and red line twice per packet and also clean-up the WAN/LAN mess a little.

In total, it's still a rather hacky setup and **I'm wondering whether there's a more elegant solution that I'm overlooking.**

I'm sorry if my setup has caused irreparable damage to your eyesight. I've never worked with this kind of ethernet connection layout.

Comment: Why would someone even wire it this way? It doesn't make sense for Ethernet and it doesn't make sense for telephone, to my knowledge... (Were they planning for Token Ring?) Do the jacks at least have all 4 pairs wired?

Comment: @grawity I don't know either. The electrician said that they were supposed to be "incoming" and "outgoing" connections, whatever that is supposed to mean in the context of ethernet. I'd much rather have a star topology converging in the hallway or room A.

Comment: And no, the cables are not wired correctly. The green and yellow line are dead and the red one drops down to 100 Mbit/s. But since we've already made an appointment with the electrician to come in and fix that, I didn't include it in the post.

Comment: I’m assuming you overlooked the most elegant solution - rewire the house properly. :)

Comment: Your terminology seem wrong.  *"RJ45 socket"* seems to be a wall plate.  *"Slot"* seems to the actual RJ-45 socket.  The wiring seems like an ordinary daisy-chained telephone line, but each segment is severed and upgraded to better UTP and dual sockets.

Comment: @sawdust Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I replaced the relevant phrases in the question post. Regarding the daisy-chain: Seems so. It doesn't make any sense for Ethernet though, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The router is a Fritzbox 4040 with a WAN port and 4 LAN ports. It is connected to the network on both the WAN port and one of its LAN ports. The activity lights on the hallway switch indicate that the router is absolutely spamming itself between its own two ports so I assume that putting WAN and LAN on the same network is not a very pretty solution

I can't guess offhand *why* it causes the bad behavior; it seems theoretically doable (but very ugly).

But the usual method of multiplexing several networks onto one Ethernet cable is to use VLANs – i.e. have an 802.1Q-capable switch on each end of the cable to do the job. (Yes, the networks would still share speed. But if you have two networks on a 1 Gbps link, that's 500 Mbps each, isn't it.)

> I thought about simply connecting the two slots of every RJ45 socket. This would effectively connect all the RJ45 sockets to a kind of bus network. Would this cause noticeable performance penalties due to collisions? Note: The total length of the line would be less than 100m.

Gigabit Ethernet only supports point-to-point, full-duplex connections – the data rate is too high to deal with collisions in shared (bus) mode. So you'd be limited to the 100 Mbps mode in the best case, with the speed *quickly* dropping down the more hosts try to talk.

(Even then, I'm not entirely sure whether twisted-pair Ethernet allows 3-way connections without a hub. I suspect that it either doesn't, or wouldn't work really well at all.)

> Is there a better way to connect the rooms that doesn't require such a huge amount of switches?

I'd say no, if all rooms require Ethernet. 3 switches isn't that many.

Yes, in your situation it would be best to have the router alongside the modem and connect dedicated access points (possibly several).